# Dividir um data frame e salvar em distintos diretórios

Tags: r, data.frame

Estou com um data frame composto de 100 linhas e duas colunas (nome e quantidade). A coluna quantidade é um número inteiro que varia de 1 a 4. Como eu posso dividir meu data frame original em quatro data frames seguindo a coluna 2 (quantidade)?

Em outras palavras, espero o seguinte resultado, após a divisão: data frame 01, com 20 linhas de quantidade 01. Data frame 02, com 25 linhas com quantidade 02. Data frame 03, com 30 linhas de quantidade 03 e data frame 03, com 25 linhas de quantidade 04. Este é um exemplo fictício.

Comment: Não ficou claro para mim o que significa o trecho "salvar em distintos diretórios" no título da pergunta. O corpo da questão não faz nenhuma referência a salvar os data frames criados.

Answer (score 4):

Esse é o caso ideal para a função `split`. Com a função `split` você pode dividir seu `data.frame` de acordo com os valores da coluna `Quantidade`:

```
tab_split <- split(tab, tab$Quantidade)
```

O resultado no comando acima foi salvo em uma lista com os quatro `data.frames` separados:

```
str(tab_split)
    List of 4
     $ 1:'data.frame':  20 obs. of  2 variables:
      ..$ Nome      : Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 22 2 12 5 25 22 24 15 20 19 ...
      ..$ Quantidade: num [1:20] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ 2:'data.frame':  25 obs. of  2 variables:
      ..$ Nome      : Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 26 10 20 17 20 21 1 1 14 20 ...
      ..$ Quantidade: num [1:25] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ 3:'data.frame':  30 obs. of  2 variables:
      ..$ Nome      : Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 24 21 1 19 24 13 6 22 25 15 ...
      ..$ Quantidade: num [1:30] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
     $ 4:'data.frame':  25 obs. of  2 variables:
      ..$ Nome      : Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 8 22 25 3 5 21 23 12 5 8 ...
      ..$ Quantidade: num [1:25] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
```

Eu recomendo deixar os quatro data.frames na lista, é mais fácil e mais organizado para trabalhar. Mas caso você queira colocar os data.frames no ambiente global basta utilizar `list2env()`:

```
names(tab_split) <- paste0("df", seq_along(tab_split))
list2env(tab_split, envir = globalenv())
```

Answer (score 3):

Outras duas maneiras de resolver o problema. A primeira delas utiliza o pacote `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
tab01 <- tab %>%
  filter(Quantidade==1)
tab02 <- tab %>%
  filter(Quantidade==2)
tab03 <- tab %>%
  filter(Quantidade==3)
tab04 <- tab %>%
  filter(Quantidade==4)
```

A segunda utiliza o comando `subset`:

```
tab01 <- subset(tab, Quantidade==1)
tab02 <- subset(tab, Quantidade==2)
tab03 <- subset(tab, Quantidade==3)
tab04 <- subset(tab, Quantidade==4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tab <- data.frame("Nome" = sample(LETTERS, 100, rep = T),
                  "Quantidade" = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,25),rep(3,30),rep(4,25)))
tab1 <- tab[which(tab$Quantidade == 1),]
tab2 <- tab[which(tab$Quantidade == 2),]
tab3 <- tab[which(tab$Quantidade == 3),]
tab4 <- tab[which(tab$Quantidade == 4),]
```